# Can't style radio buttons bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added inline stylesheet to color the two radio button, but the two radio buttons remain blue, they don't became red or green. 
This is the code, could you please help me find the bug in my code?

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
       <!-- Bootstrap -->
     
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body> <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<div class="form-group">
             <label for="btn-group" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Sections</label>

        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" style ="background-color:red;" checked > True
  </label>
         
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" style="background-color: green;" autocomplete="off"> False
  </label>
</div></div>
</form><!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
         });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
</body>

     </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the class `btn-primary` to `btn-success` to became green and `btn-danger` to become red

Answer (score 1):

You are styling the radio button itself but the thing that is making the button blue is the label that is containing it. Try this

```
 <label class="btn btn-primary active" style ="background-color:red;">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked > True
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: green;">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> False
  </label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!